# Figure out what bytes when added together equal another byte

Tags: c#

I am writing a C# program that modifies a binary file.  In the file there is a byte that stores ALL the information on what a person is wearing.

**Example:**

1 = Hat

2 = Shoes

4 = Socks

8 = Pants

16 = Shirt

32 = Glasses

64 = Watch

128 = Earrings

Sally is wearing shoes, pants and a shirt = 2 + 8 + 16 = 26. The byte stored is **26**.

Fred is wearing a hat, shoes, socks, paints, shirt, glasses and a watch: 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + 64 = 127. The byte stored is **127**

Now I want to take that number and figure out what they are wearing. A person cannot wear two of the same things, and there are only the 8 options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a [bit mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)).

Using your `2 + 8 + 16 = 26` example, you can pull out each bit using the bitwise "and" operator `&`.  To check if the person is wearing shoes, "and" the bit mask with 2 and check the result:

```
  011010 = 26
& 000010 = 2  <-- bitwise "and" operator
-------------
  000010 = 2
```

If the bitmask was 5 instead of 26, the result would be:

```
  000101 = 5
& 000010 = 2  <-- bitwise "and" operator
-------------
  000000 = 0
```

So take the result and check if it's greater than zero.  That's it:

```
bool isHat = bitMask & 1 > 0;
bool isShoes = bitMask & 2 > 0;
bool isSocks = bitMask & 4 > 0;
//and so on
```

---

FYI: I'm guessing that you are setting your bit mask by adding powers of two to an accumulator like this:

```
byte SetWatch(byte bitMask) {
    return bitMask + 64;
}
```

You can also use a bitwise operation to do this.  Use the bitwise "or" like this:

```
byte SetWatch(byte bitMask) {
    return bitMask | 64;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an enum with the `[Flags]` attribute, then use the `HasFlag` method to determine whether a given instance of the enum has that flag set.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this technique](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary#Short_Division_by_Two_with_Remainder_sub).

Referencing your example with Sally:

```
26 / 2 = 13 , Remainder = 0  <-- Hat

13 / 2 = 6  , Remainder = 1  <-- Shoes

6  / 2 = 3  , Remainder = 0  <-- Socks

3  / 2 = 1  , Remainder = 1  <-- Pants

1  / 2 = 0  , Remainder = 1  <-- Shirt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bit-wise operators to figure this out.

```
var outfit = 26; //this is the same as 2 & 8 & 16
var bIsWearingPants = ((outfit | 8) != 0);
```